# CSRF token is configured but still POST requests are not working in spring boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

I having a starnd Spring boot application and have configured csrf in my sprint security configuration as below:

```
http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and().authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/slam").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/myPage").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/contact").denyAll()
                .and().formLogin().and().httpBasic();
```

I am using CookieCsrfTokenRepository and using Postman to hit the slam API
I have authenticated myself before hitting this API and have the JSESSIONI, XSRF-TOKEN from the server side and passing it in the header to slam API

[image: Here are the headers in the POST request]

After this I am just sending the request but I am still getting the 403 forbidden.
On the other hand If I disable the CSRF token using below config . Post request is working successfully.

```
http.csrf().disable()
```

What I am missing to make CSRF token work properly through my POSTMAN's post request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the documentation from spring states the following:

> By default the CookieCsrfTokenRepository will write to a cookie named
> XSRF-TOKEN and read it from a header named X-XSRF-TOKEN or the HTTP
> parameter _csrf. These defaults come from AngularJS

In the postman image you have provided all i can see is the xsrf-token as a cookie, but no header. You need to extract the value from that cookie and send it back in a proper header, or a proper query parameter.

Comment: In my case, Spring sends the csrf cookie when we sent POST request which is too late because we need the token beforehand in order to include it in the POST but we get 403 error and csrf is included in the response